# Darboux's sums of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,2]$.

How to find $\epsilon>0$, s.t for all partition $P$ of $[1,2]$ with $\lambda(P)<\epsilon$, we will have that

$$|U_{f,P}-L_{f,P}|<0.01$$

Where $U_{f,P}$ is upper Darboux's sum, and $L_{f,P}$ lower Darboux's sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $$f(x)=\frac 1 x$$ is uniformly continuous over $[1,2]$, because it is continuous on $[1,2]$. Thus, given $\delta >0$, pick $\rho>0$ such that whenever $$|x-y|<\rho$$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\delta$$ for any choice of $x,y$.

This means in particular that if $$\lambda(P)<\rho$$ then $$\sup_{I_k} f-\inf_{I_k} f<\delta$$ over each interval $I_k=[x_{k-1},x_k]$ of the partition. It follows that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\sum_{i=1}^n \delta (x_{i}-x_{i-1})=\delta (2-1)=\delta$$

So, it all reduces to finding this $\rho$. Your function is differentiable over $(1,2)$, and by the mean value theorem, we have that for each $x,y\in(1,2)$ there is a $c$ in between for which $$\left|\frac 1 x -\frac 1 y\right|=\frac{1}{c^2}|x-y|$$ But since $x,y>1$, so is $c>1$, so over $[1,2]$

$$\left|\frac 1 x -\frac 1 y\right|=\frac{1}{c^2}|x-y|<|x-y|$$

Can you finish this off?

Comment: You got that $\delta=0.01$. Therefor $|x-y|<\rho<0.01$?

Comment: @SandraWest Yes, $\delta =\rho$ works, or anything smaller.

Answer (score -1):

**The function is decreasing**, so the $sup$ and $inf$ over the $[p_i,p_{i+1}]$ are really easy to express.

Comment: Not really, because the interval lengths in a Darboux sum don't necessarily have the same length -- so even for a monotonic function, the difference between the upper and lower sum may not telescope.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misled anybody but I never implied that the two sums would telescope. However I didn't realize (new here) that we're supposed to give a complete solution. I'll edit soon

Comment: @HenningMakholm actually you were right, this is pretty much a dead end.

Comment: @justt You needn't give a full solution.

Comment: @justt: Giving hints is fine, especially for questions like this that look like verbatim homework assignments. My comment was just because I couldn't see where this hint would lead unless it was about telescoping. (The downvote is not mine).